# Social Media Links with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, icons

I am a stuck on trying to change the size and location on social media links on a test web page. No matter what size I change the height and width to in the CSS the image remains super large.

---

```css
#footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    clear:both;
    font-family:Open Sans;
}

#footer a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer img a {
  width: auto;
  height: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=“footer”><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sophie.amberkar"><img src="facebook.png"></a></div>
<div id=“footer”><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/samberkar"> <img src="pinterest.png"></a></div>
<div id=“footer”><a href="http://www.instagram.com/samberkar"> <img src="instagram.png"></a></div>
<div id=“footer”><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/sophie-amberkar-80255746"><img src="linkedin.png"></a></div>
```

Comment: `#footer img a` should be `#footer a img`

Comment: and are you sure you are editing the right .css file?

Comment: So I actually was able to change the size of the image by using.... a img { }.....however I am not able to manipulate the positioning on the page. I am trying to get the icons to float to the middle. And yes, I am editing the right css file....that was my first thought as well.

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34171009/2733146)

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of position, the img tag is actually inside a tag, so the one with

```
#footer img a{}
```

should be changed into

```
#footer a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Agung! I just tried your advice, but I got the same result, the image position and size did not change.

Comment: Hi I have tested this code and its changing height and width of image. Please try this code: #footer a img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 35px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tested this code and its changing height and width of image. Please try this code: `#footer a img { height: 30px; width: 35px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
}
```

To center the hyperlinks, try this:

```
#footer {
  /* other styles */
  text-align: center;
}
```

If that didn't work, try removing `inline-block` from `a`

```
#footer a {
  display: inline-block; /* remove this line, if needed. */
}
```